# Prove $P(E\cup F) = P(E) + P(F)$ if $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove that if $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive then $P(E\cup F) = P(E) + P(F)$.

Any idea how to prove?

Comment: This depends on what rules you're assuming. In the usual axiomatic presentation of probability spaces, countable additivity is an axiom, in which case this is just an instantiation of countable additivity. Since you're asking this question, I suspect the rules you've been provided with are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two events are sets, than the union of them must avoid taking into account their intersection twice. For two events $X$ and $Y$,

$$P(X \cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X \cap Y)$$

And the result follows immediately.

Why does the above statement imply they are mutually exclusive? What does it mean for two events to be mutually exclusive (or two sets)?

Edit:

The proof is as follows, since the union of two events is defined as above, then that means $P(X \cap Y) = 0$, therefore, they have no shared events/probabilities between them, so they are mutually exclusive by definition.

Comment: Good question, but i also don't know as it was written like this in the question. By the way, can you elaborate this answer in little detail in the form of a prove if you don't mind? Thanks!

Comment: I added in a small proof, please let me know if you understand my explanation

Comment: I do understand it and appreciate it, but I need to solve it for homework and I am worried if I write this much length small proof then maybe my instructor didn't like it as he was assuming some solid proof.

Answer (score 0):

As written by Ephemeral, for any events $E$ and $F$,
$$ P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F) - P(E \cap F).$$
Since the events are mutually exclusive, you have by definition of mutually exclusive events
$$P(E \cap F) = 0$$
and the above "formula" reduces to
$$P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F)$$
as desired.